# ListBox not updating on SelectedItems.Add()

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, selecteditem, selectedvalue

I'm trying to bind a multiple selection listbox to a `list<int>`(IdProv) I have. what I do is binding the SelectedValue to a property that adds or removes that value to the `list<int>`. both `list<int>` and listbox.SelectedItems should be synchronized.

The listbox's xaml code looks like this:

```
            <ListBox DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                     SelectedValuePath="Id"
                     SelectedValue="{Binding Path=IdProv,
                                    Mode=OneWayToSource,
                                    ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"
                     SelectionMode="Multiple" />
```

the ItemsSource is set in the code-behind. it's a list of products that have an Id and a Name property

the problem resides in the SelectedValue property that doesn't get updated correctly (neither SelectedItem). They are setted only when the first item is selected, but then they get updated.

also when selecting an item making a click on the list, the SelectedValue just updates when I click the item that was first added.

any idea what's going on? I'm sure I made a silly mistake in bindings, but this took me hours and I can't figure it out!

thanks, Martín

Comment: I have one question. Are you trying to have multiselection from a listbox and you want to bind that? i.e. you want a bindable multi selection on listbox

Comment: yes. binding the `list<int>` to `SelectedItems` directly would be great, but I think that's more difficult (because I want to bind to each item's Id property)

Comment: These links might help. How can I update a listbox item (C#)? - http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=554717 Bind ArrayList to ListBox - [http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0460__GUI-Windows-Forms/BindArrayListtoListBox.htm](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0460__GUI-Windows-Forms/BindArrayListtoListBox.htm)

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, but I couldn't find any answer there. I know how to do the binding. my problem is that SelectedValue gets updated only on the first ".SelectedItems.Add()" or the first click on an item list. if you found something that I missed please let me know!

Comment: This link surely help you. http://denismorozov.blogspot.in/2010/07/wpf-listboxselecteditemsadd-doesnt.html Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple hack, which i'm not happy with, but resolves the problem. I wrote this SelectionChanged handler that takes care of setting the property that SelectedValue isn't updating:

```
    private void idProveedorListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox list = (ListBox)sender;
        if (list.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
        {
            ProdList.Last().IdProv.Clear();
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            Models.Proveedor lastSelected = list.SelectedItems[list.SelectedItems.Count - 1] as Models.Proveedor;
            if (lastSelected != list.SelectedItem)
                PProdList.Last().IdProveedorInt = lastSelected.Id;
        }
    }
```